# Sort and add column to file with tabbed delimiter in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I told a friend I would help him with homework and I bit off more than I can chew. My bash skills are really dusty.

I have a text file with an arbitrary number of rows, 3 columns

```
Lap1 Lap2 Lap3
33.2 33.0 31.9
33.1 32.1 30.9
34.1 33.8 33.7
...
```

And I'd like to add an averages column, and sort by that column.

I suppose I could cp the original file to my newLapTimes.txt, then get the average through

```
total=$(awk { if (NR!=1) { print $1+$2+$3 }}) lapTimes.txt
rows=$(awk {print NR} lapTimes.txt)
average=$(expr $total/$rows)
```

and add that to the end of each line in my copied newLapTimes.txt

Then I would just `sort -nk4 newLapTimes.txt -o newLapTimes.txt`

but this seems really improper if it's even correct.

I'm hoping for an answer that is a clean methodical script instead of a terse one-liner.

Comment: There is probably a better way to do that but I would use awk to calculate the average and sort to sort it afterward. Basically if the file is reasonable you can sort it in memory using awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a naive approach that sorts externally.

```
$ { echo "Lap1 Lap2 Lap3 Average"; awk -v OFMT='%.1f' 'NR>1{print $1, $2, $3, ($1+$2+$3)/3}' input.txt | sort -k 4n,4; } > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
Lap1 Lap2 Lap3 Average
33.1 32.1 30.9 32.0
33.2 33.0 31.9 32.7
34.1 33.8 33.7 33.9
```

EDIT: Here is a "`bash`" version that uses `bc` to calculate a float average. If you don't need floating point arithmetic at all (not even for the average) then you can use the commented line instead and change the formatting string to use integers (`%d`).

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Lap1\tLap2\tLap3\tAverage\n"
{
        while read x y z; do
                #(( average = (x + y + z) / 3 ))
                average=$(bc <<< "scale=2; ($x + $y + $z) / 3" 2>/dev/null)
                printf "%.1f\t%.1f\t%.1f\t%.1f\n" "${x}" "${y}" "${z}" "${average}"
        done < <(tail -n +2 input.txt)
} | sort -k 4n,4
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
Lap1    Lap2    Lap3    Average
33.1    32.1    30.9    32.0
33.2    33.0    31.9    32.7
34.1    33.8    33.7    33.9
```

Comment: Awesome. A little more compact and awk-reliant that I had hoped, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: @user `bash` itself doesn't do floating point arithmetic so any "native" shell solution would rely on external tools and be far more verbose (and slower). You could do the *whole* thing in `awk` instead but there's probably no need to and this reads easily.

Comment: Well my above example is just a generalization, and luckily the actual data I'm working with is all integers, but thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: @user I added another one and a half solutions, if floating point arithmetic is not needed at all you can use the shell's inbuilt capabilities.

Comment: @user Check the body of the `while` loop: `done < <(tail -n +2 input.txt)`. The idiom is explained [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and process substitution itself is explained [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution). Simplified, you are redirecting the output of `tail <file>` "into" the processing loop.

Comment: One last thing. I'm trying to sort in descending order, but the -r reversal flag doesn't seem to take effect. Know what that's about?

Comment: Ahh, found it. `sort -k 4nr` not `sort -r -k 4n`